# Email Validator RxSwift?

Tags: swift, validation, email-validation, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift

```
pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.0'
pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.0'
```

I saw examples of username, password validation, as it works like

```
 func validateUsername(_ username: String) -> Observable<ValidationResult> {
        if username.isEmpty {
            return .just(.empty)
        }


        // this obviously won't be
        if username.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted) != nil {
            return .just(.failed(message: "Username can only contain numbers or digits"))
        }

        // this obviously won't be
        if username.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted) != nil {
            return .just(.failed(message: "Username can only contain numbers or digits"))
        }

        let loadingValue = ValidationResult.validating

        return API
            .usernameAvailable(username)
            .map { available in
                if available {
                    return .ok(message: "Username available")
                }
                else {
                    return .failed(message: "Username already taken")
                }
            }
            .startWith(loadingValue)
    }
```

Now, I need to make validator for Email, I didn't find anything in examples how to do it?

I used to use Validator
https://github.com/SwiftValidatorCommunity/SwiftValidator

validator.registerField(emailTextField, errorLabel: emailErrorLabel, rules: [RequiredRule(), EmailRule(message: "Invalid email")])

But in Rx, I am totally confused to how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
final class EmailValidator {

    func validate(_ input: String) -> Bool {
        guard
            let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(
                pattern: "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}",
                options: [.caseInsensitive]
            )
        else {
            assertionFailure("Regex not valid")
            return false
        }

        let regexFirstMatch = regex
            .firstMatch(
                in: input,
                options: [],
                range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.count)
            )

        return regexFirstMatch != nil
    }
}
```

example usage:

```
let emailTextField = UITextField()
let emailValidator = EmailValidator()

emailTextField.rx.text
   .orEmpty
   .map(emailValidator.validate)
   .subscribe(onNext: { isValid in
       print(isValid)
   })
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```